# Introduction to reflected Brownian motion: Reference Recommendation

Tags: reference-request, brownian-motion, book-recommendation

I am trying to learn the reflected Brownian motions/processes and am looking for some comprehensive introductory books.
I have a fairly good background on real analysis (measure), and a graduate level probability (such as limit theorems). I know Ito integration, however, not very familiar with it. 
Also, I've never encountered Polish space and Skorohod space/topology.

I hope I provided enough backgrounds of me and any recommendations will be very appreciated. Thanks.